# Unable to Mount CIFS Share at Boot Using /etc/fstab - Permission Denied

Tags: cifs, shared-folders

I am facing an issue with mounting a CIFS share at system startup using /etc/fstab. Here's what I have done so far:

I can successfully mount the CIFS share manually using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=bcadmin,password='PASSWORD' //172.16.2.131/TEST/ /media/bcadmin/2cd14d9c-260e-4aa5-ace3-5f2c4befb970/Sync/shared_folder
```

To mount the share at boot, I added the following line to my /etc/fstab file:

```
//172.16.2.131/TEST/ /media/bcadmin/2cd14d9c-260e-4aa5-ace3-5f2c4befb970/Sync/shared_folder cifs username=bcadmin,password='PASSWORD',uid=bcadmin,gid=1001 0 0
```

After modifying /etc/fstab, I ran the following command to mount all entries in /etc/fstab:

```
sudo mount -a
```

However, I encountered the following error:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

I have ensured that the credentials are correct and that the share can be mounted manually. What could be causing this permission issue when attempting to mount the share at boot?

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: your mountpoint entry seems a bit odd. It would normally be just a directory which you have created for it such as `/media/<dir_name> and the uid entry something on the lines `uid=1000`

Comment: Same Issue. Also, I tried to remove the password param and add this to /etc/fstab
``
//172.16.2.131/TEST/ /media/bcadmin/shared_folder cifs username=bcadmin,uid=1000,gid=1001 0 0
``

Then I executed sudo mount -a it asked me to enter the password and after that it works perfectly

Comment: In brief, the problem just appears when I added the password option to fstab

Comment: try changing the UID from `bcasmin` to 1000. Does that then work?

Comment: I am not 100% sure that this will work, but I do know that when you manually mount anything the `/etc/mtab` file shows you a line that you can copy and paste into your `/etc/fstab` file that should work.  I had to use it for one of my NFS mounts I had so it worked properly.  Run `grep cifs | /etc/mtab` after you have it manually mounted and it should produce the line that you can use.